# Complex conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have 2 versions of a component, one mobile responsive version and one desktop. Now there are several conditions to be met before either component is rendered as you can see below:

```
{condition &&
    !otherCondition &&
    (size === "small" || size === "extra-small") && (
        <MobileComponent />
    )}

{condition &&
    !otherCondition &&
    (size !== "small" || size !== "extra-small") && (
        <DesktopComponent />
    )}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and both the Mobile and Desktop version of the component are rendered. It only becomes problematic on the `(size === "small" || size === "extra-small")` part where in I want to say:

If size is `small` or size is `extra small` then show the mobile component.

Then vice versa...

If size is NOT `small` or size is NOT `extra small` then show the desktop component.

Note that the `small` value changes whenever I resize the screen. So the value is there just that there's something wrong with the way I do the condition.

Comment: Think the desktop condition should be if size is NOT `small` AND it's NOT `extra-small`, rather than OR. The OR makes that condition evaluate to true because if it's `small`, `size !== "extra-small"` will be true, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(size === "small" || size === "extra-small")` can be negated as either

```
!(size === "small" || size === "extra-small")
```

or

```
(size !== "small" && size !== "extra-small")
```

Notice that both `===` and logical OR are changed.

Since the same condition is used twice, a DRYer and more readable way to write it is:

```
const isMobile = condition && !otherCondition && (size === "small" || size === "extra-small");
...
{isMobile && <MobileComponent />}
...
{!isMobile && <DesktopComponent />}
```

If components go in succession then a ternary should be used:

```
{isMobile ? <MobileComponent /> : <DesktopComponent />}
```

Answer (score 2):

i believe that is what you intend to do:

```
{condition &&
    !otherCondition &&
    (size !== "small" && size !== "extra-small") && (
        <DesktopComponent />
    )}
```

the problem was in case where size="small" and then both of your condition evaluated as true.(in `<MobileComponent>` it is obvious and in  `<DesktopComponent>` because "small"  is in fact different from "extra-small"

Answer (score 1):

Try with ternary operator like below

```
   {condition && !otherCondition && (size === "small" || size === "extra-small") ? <MobileComponent /> : <DesktopComponent />}
```